# Divide a Javascript Array and subarrays In 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
var myArray = [ 
    { familyName: 'one', subfamilies: 
        [ { subfamilyName: 'subOne', subItems: 
             [ { name: 'subOne', code: '1' }, 
               { name: 'subTwo', code: '2' } 
             ] } 
        ] 
     }, 
    { familyName: 'two', subfamilies: 
        [ { subfamilyName: 'subTwo', subItems: 
             [ { name: 'subOne', code: '1' }, 
               { name: 'subTwo', code: '2' },
               { name: 'subTwo', code: '3' }
             ] } 
        ] 
     } 
]
```

I need to divide that array in two diferent arrays with the same length if possible (my real array is so much longer), but I am having some problems getting it done. I create 2 blank array and, with for sentence read all the items. First I push the subItems in one blank array, but cannot get the way to create a new subFamily in a blank array variable and then push the sutItems array.

How can be this done?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What would your desired output be? could you draw the JS.

Comment: `var firstArray = myArray[0]; var secondArray = myArray[1];`?

Comment: My output must be an array with the first elements.

Imagine this, I have 12 families of cars, with X subfamilies each and Y models each subfamily. I have to distribute the items of a family in 2 divs to make 2 columns, so I have to divide in 2 and take the first half for the left column and the rest of the items and subamilies en the right one.

Comment: Why split them in the first place when you can map them directly to the divs you need from an iteration or two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myOtherArray = myArray.splice(myArray.length / 2 | 0);
```